# Android - html link in TextView around word is making the entire link clickable. How to stop that?

Tags: android, textview

I have an app where i am displaying dynamic text in a TextView.   The text is has

```
text_view.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
text_view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Within the text in the TextView i have html links around particular words.  The links work, however as you scroll with your finger down the page, you will sometimes accidentally click the link and be redirected on accident.

The issue seems to be that the word that is the link, is not the only thing that becomes clickable.  It appears that the entire line on the page becomes a link.

Example text in the TextView:

```
TEAM1 @ TEAM2
STATUS:  FINAL
LINK: ESPN
```

The "ESPN" is suppose to be the only item in the list that is clickable.

Do you have any ideas on how to correct this?

Addition:

Here is my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:visibility="visible" />

  <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/widget_date"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      android:visibility="visible" />

  <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/widget_text"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="16dp"
      android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in my code i am setting the html links around the word ESPN as such:
Loop through data and create dynamic link based on data append to larger string, the string scores set in the TextView below is just a string that contains the string "link" in html format.

```
String link = "LINK: " + "<a href = \""+ game.getUrl() +  "\">ESPN</a><BR><BR>");
text_view.setText(Html.fromHtml(scores));
```

When all is said and done i have what i need.  Only problem is when you start to use your finger to scroll down the page, you will sometimes kick off the link due to the fact that it appears that the link spans the entire row, including the blank spaces.  So your finger accidentatily hits a link everyone once in a while.  All i want is for the link to only kick off when you specifically click on the word "ESPN" not on the white space.

[image]

Changing the string to actually include spaces after the closing  tag, made the white space no longer clickable.

```
"LINK: " + "<a href = \""+ game.getUrl() +  "\">ESPN</a>             <BR><BR>");
```

strange band aid but it works.

Comment: sure, i posted some additional details to make things clearer.

Comment: You are 100% correct that is the problem.  If i click anywhere on the same line that has the ESPN, even white space, it will execute the link and redirect to the browser.  Which makes scrolling a bit difficult.  As far as the \,  i am just escaping the double quote.

Comment: Well i just found the solution.  The string that i end up passing to the TextView, although it contains html elements it is not html. If i include spaces after the closing </a> tag, the white space is no longer clickable and you can only go to the link if you click on "ESPN".   Ill post above what i did.  Dont think its a permanent solution just a band aid.

Comment: This helped me - http://jtomlinson.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/textview-and-html.html

Answer (score 0):

Per Lt. Tuvok (since he didn't close it...): The string that i end up passing to the TextView, although it contains html elements it is not html. If i include spaces after the closing  tag, the white space is no longer clickable and you can only go to the link if you click on "ESPN". Ill post above what i did. Dont think its a permanent solution just a band aid.